# How to invoke external build scripts?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

How do I execute another FAKE build script from within a FAKE build script?

I want to create a build script which clones a git repo and then executes a build script within the cloned project. After that it should tag the branch and publish the build artifact to a Nexus Repository Manager.

Also I want to hand over some parameter to the external build script, e.g. a version tag.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
Target "ReleaseBuild" (fun _ ->
    CleanDir "src"
    cloneSingleBranch "" "http://<URL to git-repo>" "master" "src"

    ?????  "src/build.fsx" versionNumer

    ... tagging etc. ...
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? A cleaner way is to `#load` the other script and call functions from it. Gives you type safety and more control.

Comment: That sounds like an appropriate solution for my original problem.

Comment: Posted it as an answer with a little example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to modularize your build is not by calling FAKE within FAKE, but by having FSI load modules using the `#load` directive.

For example:

```
// build.fsx
#r "path/to/FakeLib.dll"
#load "./OtherModule.fsx"
open Fake

Target "ReleaseBuild" <| fun _ ->
    CleanDir "src" 
    cloneSingleBranch "" "http://<URL to git-repo>" "master" "src" 

    OtherModule.DoWhatever versionNumer

...


// OtherModule.fsx

let DoWhatever version =
    ...
```

.
**EDIT** (in response to comment)
If the other script file doesn't exist when the first one starts, then you could execute it using [`FSIHelper.executeFSI`](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-fsihelper.html):

```
Target "ReleaseBuild" <| fun _ ->
    CleanDir "src" 
    cloneSingleBranch "" "http://<URL to git-repo>" "master" "src" 

    let result, messages = FSIHelper.executeFSI "src" "build.fsx" []

    ...
```

(or `executeFSIWithArgs` if you need to pass arguments)

If even this doesn't work for you for some reason, I would just resort to executing it as a regular shell command, using `Shell.Exec`:

```
Target "ReleaseBuild" <| fun _ ->
    CleanDir "src" 
    cloneSingleBranch "" "http://<URL to git-repo>" "master" "src" 

    let errCode = Shell.Exec ("path/to/fake.exe", args = "src/build.fsx")

    ...
```

But if you want this to be cross-platform, it gets a bit complicated: `*.exe` won't execute natively on UNIX, you need to run `mono` and give the `.exe` file as argument. To work around that, you'd need to wrap `fake.exe` in a shell script (two scripts - one for Windows, one for UNIX), and then pass the name of that script as argument into the FAKE script.

Comment: I have just found out that it does not work for me. I can't #load the external build file because it's not there when the build is started.